# Transposing every 5th value from a row in worksheet to a column in another worksheet

Tags: xml, excel, indexing, offset, worksheet

Apprentice Sheet Example:

[image: Apprentice Sheet Example]

Summary Sheet Example:

[image: Summary Sheet Example]

I am trying to take information from the Apprentice Sheet that is on a row (every 4th column from the beginning cell at B3) and transpose it onto my Summary Sheet. Ideally the information from the Apprentice sheet (classifications and rates) should summarize into respective columns on the Summary sheet.

I've tried the OFFSET and INDEX functions but I am only returning one value or the wrong values.

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013.

Comment: So you could use the Power Query addin, to transform the data.

Comment: so i just downloaded the power query.  i hope it's relatively easy to use. i'm on a time crunch. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, in Power Query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(Source),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Transposed Table",{"Column2"}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Columns", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Column1", "Name"}, {"Column2", "Class"}, {"Column3", "Type"}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns", each [Type] <> null and [Type] <> ""),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name"}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Filled Down", {"Name", "Class", "Type"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Type]), "Type", "Value", List.Sum),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Pivoted Column", each ([Attribute] = "Base Rate Payroll"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows1"
```

Comment: Is there a more basic excel formula?  I have no coding experience at all.  Perhaps this was the wrong forum to ask such a question. lol i'm so sorry for my lack of intelligence on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason `INDEX` wouldn't work. If "Dennis Akin" is in `B3` in the Apprentice worksheet and you want "Dennis Akin" in `B3` of the Summary worksheet, use these formulas in the Summary worksheet:

EMP NAME:

```
=INDEX(Apprentice!$B$3:$U$8,1,(ROW()-ROW($B$3))*4+1)
```

CLASS:

```
=INDEX(Apprentice!$B$3:$U$8,3,(ROW()-ROW($B$3))*4+1)
```

ST:

```
=INDEX(Apprentice!$B$3:$U$8,5,(ROW()-ROW($B$3))*4+1)
```

OT:

```
=INDEX(Apprentice!$B$3:$U$8,5,(ROW()-ROW($B$3))*4+2)
```

DT:

```
=INDEX(Apprentice!$B$3:$U$8,5,(ROW()-ROW($B$3))*4+3)
```

Comment: Dennis Akin is not in the B3 cell of the Apprentice sheet. The name Dennis Akin is part of merged cells on the Apprentice worksheet, see top example.  I'm new to StackFlow so is there anyway to attach a sample excel workbook?

Comment: When you click on Dennis Akin, what does the Name Box (the box left of the Formula Bar) say?

Comment: Actually, I think this is working for the class.  I just tweeked the formula to go through DP column instead of U so that it encompassed all my data and it's working now.  I also changed 3 to 1 and it picked up the classes perfectly. :)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: These formulas worked great once I tweeked it to match the data I needed; however, when I try to use the same formula (but a different work sheet name) on the same column (same column in the Summary sheet) but obviously a lower cell down the column, I get a #ref error. Everything is the same as the formulas as I previously used except the worksheet name. I even tried to copy and paste the original formula much lower in the column but I still get the #ref error.  I don't receive the #ref error if I use a different column on the Summary sheet.

Comment: `(ROW()-ROW($B$3))*4+1` tells `INDEX` which column to look in. For each row the formula is filled down, it will move 4 columns over. So if you fill the formula down to `B13`, it will look in the 41st column of `$B$3:$U$8`. If you want to append data from a new sheet, you need to change `$B$3` in `ROW($B$3)` to the cell holding the first output from the new sheet. You can then fill that new formula down to get the rest of the data from the new sheet.